# Django Celery cannot get access to redis running on another raspberry pi

Tags: django, redis, celery

I'm currently following [this](https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/) tutorial on how to set up celery.

I want to use my Raspbery Pi for the redis server, thus I have installed `redis` on it, and it works.

Now, in the Django project I have defined

```py
#settings.py

CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://192.168.0.21:6379"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://192.168.0.21:6379"
```

(where the IP-address is the IP of my Raspberry running the redis server)

but my local computer cannot access the redis server; the command `python -m celery -A django_celery worker`
throws the error

```
 ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://192.168.0.21:6379//: DENIED 
Redis is running in protected mode because protected mode is enabled, no bind address was specified,
 no authentication password is requested to clients.
In this mode connections are only accepted from the loopback interface. 
If you want to connect from external computers to Redis you may adopt one 
of the following solutions: 
1) Just disable protected mode sending the command 'CONFIG SET protected-mode no' 
from the loopback interface by connecting to Redis from the same host the server 
is running, however MAKE SURE Redis is not publicly accessible from internet if you do so. Use CONFIG REWRITE to make this change permanent.
2) Alternatively you can just disable the protected mode by editing
 the Redis configuration file, and setting the protected mode option to 'no', and then restarting the server.
3) If you started the server manually just for testing, restart it with the '--protected-mode no' option.
4) Setup a bind address or an authentication password.
NOTE: You only need to do 
one of the above things in order for the server to start
 accepting connections from the outside..
```

eventho I have editted the "redis.config" with

```
bind 192.168.0.11
```

with that IP being the IP of my local computer.

I have tried uncomment all the `bind` commands and set `protected-mode no`, but that does not make any difference.

I know the IP-address is correct to the Raspberry, since I can SSH into it with that IP-address.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try connecting to the server using redis cli first.

Comment: I can connect to it, but if I then type `ping` the same error occurs.
I have setting `protected-mode no` thus it is wierd that the says that protected mode is on

Comment: Are you using your local computer redis cli to connect to the raspberry pi redis?

Comment: Yes, using `redis-cli 198.168.0.20 -p 6379`

The "terminal" pops up, but then typing "ping" throws the error

Comment: It is like the redis config is not applied

Comment: Ok, because I don't know how your redis is started, I will start `./redis-server redis.conf` like this.

Comment: Yeah, when I do that nothing happnes. No error, no nothing

Comment: Because it doesn't seem to be a celery problem, it's the redis that cannot be connected to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: So can you ping 198.168.0.20 ?

Comment: The issue is, I think, that redis doesnt load the config file (it actually says that when I start the server and `INFO server` shows no config-file aswell)

Comment: I just tested with two computers, there is no problem, `protected-mode no` and `bind 0.0.0.0` or `bind 192.168.0.11`, try this first.

Comment: Because you want to connect `192.168.0.11` to `192.168.0.21`, the redis of `192.168.0.21` should be changed to bind `192.168.0.21`, and `192.168.0.11` does not need to be changed.